# How to map columns from CSV to the class properties in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

**TO DO**

To create a console application, which can read a CSV file and auto determine to which of the three CSV files(varies in column data) it belongs to.

I have created a console application, which is currently reading all the csv files from the directory using SmartXLS library.

How can I read in the data for each file into a list and have a simple mechanism for mapping each "column" of data with the associated class property (i.e. column name) I have defined in my class?

**File structure 1:**

Usage Date,Product Name,User Id,Tokens Used

1. 20160428,Samsung,dorman@stackoverflow.com

**File structure 2:**

Reason, Month, Adjustment Date, Transaction ID, Tokens Adjusted, Product Name, Comment Added

1. Off network, 15-Oct, 31-Oct-15,73820274918-230934049372,045, Xbox, Bridge Design for InfraWorks 360.

**File structure 3:**

Usage Date, Product Name, Product Version, User Id, Machine Name, Server Name, Tokens Used, Hours Used

1. 20161027, Gamepro, 2016, 11597, BC318010, LA847012, 6, 0.1

Kindly, help me in re-writing the function.

Class:

```
public class Token
     {
            public DateTime Usagedate { get; set; }
            public string Product_name { get; set; }
            public string Product_Version { get; set; }
            public string Userid { get; set; }
            public string User_name { get; set; }
            public string Machine_name { get; set; }
            public string Server_name { get; set; }
            public string Tokens_used { get; set; }
            public string Use_count { get; set; }

        }
```

App:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class token
    {
        public List<Token> Tokens { get; set; }
        public void TokenData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Begin Harvesting");

            CategorizeData();//function
        }

 public void CategorizeData()
        {
            int count = 0;

            Tokens = new List<Token>();

            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Projects", "*.csv");

            foreach (string file in files)
            {

                SmartXLS.WorkBook WB = new WorkBook();
                WB.readCSV(file);

                DataTable dt = WB.ExportDataTable();

                string dtSTR;
                DataRow dr;
                DataColumn dc;
                for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    dr = dt.Rows[i];

                   try
                   {
                       // Map Columns with the class properties
                       // read them to the list
                     dtSTR = dr[0].ToString();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSTR)) continue;

                    var tkn = new Token();


                    tkn.Usagedate = ParseDateTime(dtSTR);
                    tkn.Product_name = dr[1].ToString();
                    tkn.Userid = dr[2].ToString();
                    tkn.Tokens_used = dr[3].ToString();
                    tkn.Reason = dr[4].ToString();


                    Tokens.Add(tkn); 
                    count++;    


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { }


                }

            }
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: Why are you catching all exceptions?

Comment: @luxun. Is it not required to have it?

Comment: Not unless you intend to do something to handle the exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a CSV mapper to class before, but there is a Component called [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which I found that is very fast and actually works better than mine. and it has lots of features

```
string content = "";
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\Projects", "*.csv");
foreach (string file in files)
    content += System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file) + Environment.NewLine;

using(TextReader sr = new StringReader(content))
{
   var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
      csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TokenMap>();
      var records = csv.GetRecords<Token>();
}





public class TokenMap : CsvClassMap<Token>
{
    public TokenMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Product_name );
        Map(m => m.Product_Version);
        Map(m => m.Userid);
        Map(m => m.User_name);
        Map(m => m.Machine_name);
        Map(m => m.Server_name);
        Map(m => m.Tokens_used);
        Map(m => m.Use_count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my function as posted above, I am reading all the csv files from a directory. In your code,your reading from a single file rite?  could you suggest me how can I read all the files from my directory in this case?

Comment: I changed the code, so that suits reading csv files from a directory.

Comment: CSVHelper is great, +1

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani. I am facing a couple of errors. Do I have to create a new class called Token Map? or what part of  your code goes in to the CategorizeData() function?

Comment: Well thats a name I gave it, you should have a mapping class, with any name you like

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani.  This is the class I created: 



namespace TokenApp
{
//Error: The name Map does not exist in the current context
    class TokenMap:CsvClassMap<Token> // Displaying error
    {
        public TokenMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Product_name);
            Map(m => m.Product_Version);
            Map(m => m.Userid);
            Map(m => m.User_name);
            Map(m => m.Machine_name);
            Map(m => m.Server_name);
            Map(m => m.Tokens_used);
            Map(m => m.Use_count);
        }

    }
}

Comment: have you imported these two:` using CsvHelper;`
`using CsvHelper.Configuration;`

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani. I just imported csvHelper.configuration and it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani. Sure, but I am still trying with your code.

Have a couple of questions:
1) So i have created a Mapping class as suggested.
2) So whats Mapping class is doing is, mapping the class properties with the column data?
3)What goes in to the Categorizing function? are we writing all the class properties in to a list and parsing the data from the list?

Comment: yes it maps the csv to your class properties. you wont need Categorizing anymore. it will return an IEnumerable<Token>

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani. How can I print the list to see the data ? and what part of your code is parsing the data from the list?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani. Would you mind commenting your code. 
What I am trying to do with my app is to
1. Read all the csv files column data in to a list.
2.Parse the data from the list>

Reason: The goal is that when I give my app a new csv file, my app should be able to determine which type of the three File types(listed above) it belongs to. Can we use the data table using csv helper with your code to accomplish the goal? 

Later Stage: I will be dumping all these csv file data  in to a single Database Table. Kindly, help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153406/discussion-between-rev4-and-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani).